# Why my Apache Camel mock endpoint doesn't work in test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I want to test my apache camel rout. I have test class:

```
public class RequestTest extends CamelTestSupport {
  @Override
  protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
    applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
    return applicationContext.getBean(CamelContext.class);
  }
  @Test
  public void testDeliveryPush() throws Exception {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:start")
          .to("activemq:is2.request?requestTimeout=30s");    
        from("activemq:is2.messages")
          .to("mock:result");
      }
    });

    MockEndpoint endpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
    endpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);

    String req = "body";  
    String result = template.requestBodyAndHeader("direct:start", req, RequestProcessor.AGENT_ID, 1003, String.class);
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    endpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}
```

I can not understand why the test fails but I have message in my activeMq queue. Why the message doesn't come in mock:result endpoint?
The message was in the is2.messages
[image]

I got:
`java.lang.AssertionError: mock://result Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :<1> 
Actual   :<0>`

Answer (score 0):

You send messages to one queue (`is2.request`), but **listen on another queue** (`is2.messages`). That cannot work, the second route, and therefore the Mock endpoint never gets a message. Or is it a typo in your question?

And in your screenshot there is no message. The queue is empty. There **was** a message (messages enqueued), but it is already consumed (messages dequeued).

Comment: Thanks! No, it isn't typo. I want to check if the message was in the `is2.messages`. But how can I do it?

Comment: Am I missing something? You send a message to `is2.request` and I guess it stays there. Because nobody consumes it as far as I can see. On the other hand you listen on `is2.messages` where nobody sends messages to. To me it looks like there is a missing piece between the two queues. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: My route is described in the `camel-context.hml` file. And when I send message to `is2.request` my route works correct. In activeMQ admin panel I see messages in my other queues.

Comment: Ah, now I understand! Your route under test is the missing piece that moves messages from `is2.request` to `is2.messages`

Comment: Have you tried to use `sendBodyAndHeader` instead of `requestBodyAndHeader`? Because I guess you don't expect a response when you send a message to a queue. And what is the error message of the failing test? That the mock has not received a message?

Comment: I got `java.lang.AssertionError: mock://result Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :<1> 
Actual   :<0>` And yes, I tryed to use `sendBodyAndHeader` method.

Comment: I guess it is a problem of test initialization. You use `CamelTestSupport` (does not include Spring-Support), but you have `applicationContext` available. Is there an `@RunWith` annotation or something else in the class that you removed in your question?